# Python regex: Add "-" inside a string using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this line in my .txt file:

> 2016CT1021

I want to make it like this:

> 2016-CT-1021

I tried to use this Python regex: "re.sub":

```
data = re.sub(r'\d\d+(?:\w\w\d\d\d\d)', r'\d\d+(?:-\w\w-\d\d\d\d)', data)
```

But it didn't change/replace. Please someone help me. Thank you!

Comment: Try `^(.{4})(.{2})(.{4})$` and replace it with `\1-\2-\3`.

Comment: for current example will work `re.sub(r'(\d\d+)(\w\w)(\d\d\d\d)', r'\1-\2-\3', data)`

Comment: Yes, you can't replace \d with \d, such characters can be used for capturing only, read about backreferencing groups

Comment: @BearBrown Thank you so much sir! It solved my problem. Sorry, just a newbie on using Python regex.

Comment: @N.Omugs glad to help, added the answer for other who will search the same.

Comment: @BearBrown Sir, how bout if I want a regex patttern for this `2016-CT-1234` i tried this one `(\d\d+)\W(\w\w)\W(\d\d\d\d)` but it also match some lines in my text file like this `58 13:3917`.

Comment: why not simple `(\d\d+)-(\w\w)-(\d\d\d\d)`?

Comment: @BearBrown Oh! didn't expect that it was just like that. Thank Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current example will work

```
re.sub(r'(\d\d+)(\w\w)(\d\d\d\d)', r'\1-\2-\3', data)
```

you should group with brackets and use group number in the replace expression.